# Ensuring my MongoDB data is always sorted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some data which is stored using this Schema:

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
  ID: { type: Number, unique: true },
  created_at: { type: String },
  title: { type: String }
});
```

Each `created_at` item is stored as a string representing a time like this `2015-08-25T22:29:20.000Z`. When I first populated the database, I knew that all the items were in order according to their `created_at` value, which is great. Now, I am looking to connect to an API to retrieve *more* messages, and these messages could be in a random order and their could be a lot of them. I want to be able to take these new messages and save them to the database know that they will be in the correct order.

When retrieving more messages, I will be using a feature on the API which is something like `http://blabla.com/api/created_at>X` so I am able to run a query which returns all the new posts since `X`. So I have two things I would need help with, but they both solve each other's problem.

**1.** How would you query your database to find the message with the most recent `created_at` value?

**2.** How would you insert the data into said database ensuring it will be sorted by the `created_at` value?

I hope this isn't too vague. If it is, I'm happy to post something more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not vaugue, but it just is not possible ( in the case of **2** ). No matter what the value of a "created_at" field, you simply cannot insert one document before another. Not that it really matters anyway.

What you *"should"* be doing is creating an "index" on your "created_at" field and it should also be a `Date` type. A real `Date` stores less data than a string, and is infinitely more useful.

Doing this is a very simple addition to your schema:

```js
var messageSchema = new Schema({
  ID: { type: Number, unique: true },
  created_at: { type: Date },
  title: { type: String }
});

messageSchema.index({ "created_at": 1 })
```

Then when you query, you can efficiently "sort" with use of the index:

```js
Message.find({}).sort({ "created_at": -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function(err,results) {

    });
```

That will return the most recent document by the creation date. Which answers **2** now that **1** is already addressed

As long as you always either include query conditions that use the index ( or an index ) containing the "created_at" field, or explicitly sort on that field, then the data will be returned by order of the "created_at" date. Of course, with a compound index the order is dependant on what other keys and placement are as well.

Of course you also need to fix your data to use `Date` types. I recommend the mongodb shell and this listing for "one off" operations:

```js
var bulk = db.messages.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.messages.find(
    { "created_at": { "$type": 2 } }
).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "created_at": new Date(doc.created_at) }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.messages.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Of course it is always worth considering that the `ObjectId` of `_id` is based on a timestamp already and is "monotonic" or "ever increasing". So you might just want to explicitly sort on that instead.

```js
Message.find({}).sort({ "_id": -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function(err,results) {

    });
```

But I would change the dates anyway. Strings are not good.

Comment: Awesome, I just changed `created_at` to use the `Date` type before reading this, and have been trying out using a query with something like `find({ created_at: { $gt: new Date(something) } }}` and this is working. I am wondering which would be more efficient and better for scaling the database between the two options. One option is to just search for anything newer than X using `$gt` as above, and the second option is to sort all the items by `created_at` as you did in your example. Which do you think is better?